# Did Rumi actually say "Silence is the language of God; all else is poor translation"?

Tags: quote-source, persian-language, rumi

> Silence is the language of God; all else is poor translation.

I found this quote, like many, attributed to Rumi ([one](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/27617-silence-is-the-language-of-god-all-else-is-poor), [two](https://paulocoelhoblog.com/2015/10/02/character-of-the-week-rumi/), [three](http://thequotes.in/silence-is-the-language-of-god-all-else-is-poor-translation-rumi/) non-verifiable sources). Since Rumi quotes are [notoriously often mistranslated or misattributed](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/9117/17), this needs a better source to be sure.

**Did Rumi actually write this? If so, where?**

Answer (score 3):

It was saint john of the cross who wrote, "silence is the first language of God," and the contemporary Christian mystic, Father Thomas Keating, who added, "all else is a poor translation." But today people are very lazy about checking references and attribute every spiritual saying that sounds good to Rumi, Laotzu, or Buddha.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Please can you add some exact sources or links to make this more verifiable? E.g. where/when did Saint John of the Cross and Father Thomas Keating say these things?